# jQuery multiple requests to the server in modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it.

**HTML**
    
     Write Message

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-name="Test1 (Expert)" data-to="2" class="btn btn-default btn-sm message"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Write Message</a>

<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="msg_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="msg_modal">
...
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success pull-right send_msg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Send Message</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.message').on('click', function(e){
   $('#msg_modal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
       ...
     });
   });
});
```

My problem: When I click on .message selector - ajax loads data one time; When I close dialog window and click again on .message selector - ajax loads multiple time. 
How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like every time you click the button, it will register new listener again and again. Try separating `.modal('show')` with event `shown.bs.modal` like  so :

```
$('.message').on('click', function(e){
  $('#msg_modal').modal('show');
});

$('#msg_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
   $.ajax({
    ...
  });
});
```

You only need to register the `shown.bs.modal` listener once as `shown.bs.modal` listener will trigger automatically when `.modal('show')` called.